# Classifying Discrete time filter

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, frequency-response

So let's say i have this frequency response of a digital filter:

[image]

My question is how can i classify this type of filter ( low pass, high pass,...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a **bandpass** filter whose frequency response suppresses the **low** and **high** frequencies (with its zeros at $\omega = 0$ and $\omega = \pi$) and **amplifies** the band in between.

The **bandwidth** of the filter can be defined by reference to **$-3_{dB}$** points, which would give you approximately $W_{-3dB} \approx 0.2\pi$, with a center frequency of $\omega_c = 0.5\pi$.

I would however not consider this bandwidth to be a descriptive one.

Comment: So basically the high frequencies are $\omega =\pi$ and the low frequencies are $\omega=0$ or $\omega=2\pi$ ?

Comment: in the discrete time domain, **low frequencies** are around $\omega = 2\pi k$ and **high frequencies** are around $\omega = \pi + 2\pi k$ for $k \in Z$